# Align the android analog clock to most left

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having an xml file like this to show an analog clock on left and also display the date and time to right of that. But the problem is that i am not getting the clock aligned to left most though i tried in many ways. How can I get the clock to left most

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"   android:id="@+id/base_layout"             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:background="@drawable/bgclock"    android:gravity="left"        android:layout_gravity="left"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"     android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:gravity="left"          android:layout_gravity="left"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout   
            android:layout_weight="1 " 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"   android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"   
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:gravity="left" android:paddingLeft="0dip"  android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical">


     <LinearLayout  android:layout_marginTop="36.0dip"   android:id="@+id/clock_layout"           android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"   android:layout_gravity="left"     android:paddingLeft="0dip" android:layout_height="192.0dip" >
   <custom.analog.clock.AnalogClock1 android:id="@+id/clock"  style="@style/clock"     android:gravity="left"       android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"      android:paddingLeft="0dip"    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />



 </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout   

                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

     <!-- 1.25 -->


       <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginTop="76.0dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Digital Clock"
    android:maxLength="12"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  <DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/
    digitalClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DigitalClock" /> </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>






       <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
/>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/calculate7"
    android:layout_width="280dip"
    android:layout_height="68dip"
    android:clickable="true"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gettime" />


  </LinearLayout>


       </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, for custom.analog.clock.AnalogClock1 you only set the gravity to the left, the Layoutgravity should be "left". Or you could just set the gravity(not only Layoutgravity) of clock_layout to "left", that should align all its children to the left.

P.S please format you xml code before copying it here(ctrl + shift + F).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use relative layout. In which you could place your button, textview e.t.c where ever you want to put them with simple drag and drop.